# How to get the relevant 'this' object in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

here's the snippet of code I have:

```
$(".block").mouseover(function() {
  $("#block_title").html("title"));
});
```

Each div of class .block has a data-title attribute (value of each data-title attribute is different). I want to be able to access this data-title attribute inside my anonymous function.

Comment: Are you asking how to access the `$().data()` or are you talking about an actual html attribute called `data-title`?

Comment: Have you considered `this.getAttribute('data-title');`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access it using the `.data` method:

```
$(".block").mouseover(function() {
    ...
    $("#block_title").html($(this).data('title'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the .data() function in jQuery

```
$(".block").mouseover(function() {
  $("#block_title").html($(this).data('title'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be referring to this code.

```
$('.block').attr('data-title', 'This is a random value');
```

According to [the jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

> Get the value of an attribute for the first element in the set of matched elements or set one or more attributes for every matched element.

I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you have an **[HTML5 `data-` attribute](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes)**:

```
$(".block").mouseover(function() {
    $("#block_title").html( $(this).attr("data-title") ); //data-title value
});
```

Or, if you mean you have a `title` property in the **[jQuery arbitrary data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/)**:

```
$(".block").mouseover(function() {
    $("#block_title").html( $(this).data("title") ); //title value in the data object
});
```